# Drupal 8 view works in preview but not showing on page

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am using Drupal 8.

I have created a simple view. It is designed so that content with a taxonomy term (category) has a contextual filter.

I am wanting that a user can click on a category in an a custom content type of HowTo, and go to that category page, and on that page they can see a list of all other HowTo articles with the same category.

In the view editor, in the preview, it is working, with the contextual filter.

[image]

However, when I try this on the category page, it does not work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was the url alias pattern was `category/[term:name]` and my view url was `category/%`. I changed the alias to `[term:name]` and it started working. So now my terms can be viewed at `category/term`.

I think the taxonomy term node was overriding the view display.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, was caused by having multiple views with the same path.